# Er wird mich allein gelassen haben

Tags: grammaticality, time, future

Ein Kollege von mir hat sich über Weihnachten frei genommen, ich bin allerdings arbeiten. In einem Gespräch mit einem anderen Kollegen haben wir uns gerade gefragt, wie man das grammatikalisch korrekt ausdrückt.

Ist *"Er wird mich allein gelassen haben"* korrekt, wenn man sich auf den Zeitpunkt in der Weihnachtszeit bezieht?

Im Englischen wäre es denke ich *"He will have left me alone"*.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Welcher Zeitpunkt des Gesprächs soll gelten? Also rede ich vor Weihnachten über den Zeitpunkt Weihnachten = dass einer arbeitet und er der andere nicht, das liegt in der Zukunft?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Man weiß in der Gegenwart schon, dass man in der Zukunft von ihm alleine gelassen wird. Dieser "Zustand" soll ausgedrückt werden

Comment: Bitte der Vollständigkeit halber in die Frage reineditieren, dass das Gespräch  über den Zustand vor Eintreten des Zustands stattfindet. Damit klar ist, es gab eine Entscheidung in der Vergangenheit, die heute diskutiert wird und diskutiert wird heute deren Auswirkung in der Zukunft.

Comment: What are you willing to express saying "He will have left me alone" instead of "He is going to leave me alone"?

Comment: Eine kleine Anmerkung: "..., ich bin allerdings arbeiten" passt nicht ganz. "..., ich arbeite allerdings." oder "..., ich werde allerdings arbeiten." wären besser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Er wird mich alleine gelassen haben

ist Futur zwei, für das ich keine Notwendigkeit sehe, weil es kein zweiter Zeitpunkt in der Zukunft auf einen vorher (aber immer noch in der Zukunft) liegenden Zeitpunkt verweist.  Insofern passt die grammatikalische Form nicht zum geschilderten Zeitverhalt.

Es reicht:

> Über Weihnachten lässt mich mein Kollege allein

(wo der Zukunftsaspekt nur in der Zeitangabe steckt) oder schlimmstenfalls

> Über Weihnachten wird mich mein Kollege alleine lassen.

(Futur eins)

Comment: Also ist der Satz prinzipiell - auch grammatikalisch - richtig, aber nicht notwendig?

Comment: Er ist grammatikalisch richtig aber nicht in dem von dir beschriebenen Kontext. In der Weihnachtszeit wird er dich allein lassen. Nach der Weihnachtszeit wird er dich (in der Weihnachtszeit) allein gelassen haben.

Answer (score 2):

Wie schon in den anderen Antworten erläutert, ist "Er wird mich alleine lassen" die richtige Variante. Allerdings hat das eine leicht negative Konnotation, wie etwa in der Formulierung "die Eltern lassen ihre Kinder alleine" - da schwingt ein "im Stich lassen" mit. Das ist hier jedoch nicht gemeint, es geht um eine ganz normale Urlaubs- bzw. Abwesenheitsplanung für Weihnachten. Ich würde daher folgende Formulierung vorschlagen:

> Ich werde Weihnachten alleine arbeiten.
>
> Ich werde Weihnachten alleine im Büro sein.

Answer (score 1):

Nein, das ist leider falsch.

Die von dir gewählte Zeit heißt »Futur II«, und sie bezeichnet ein Ereignis, das zeitlich vor einem anderen Ereignis liegt. Ich nenne das frühere Ereignis das »Ereignis A« und das spätere »Ereignis B«. Futur II verwendet man genau dann, wenn man vom Ereignis A spricht und wenn das Ereignis B in der Zukunft liegt.

Ob das Ereignis A ebenfalls in der Zukunft liegt, oder in der Vergangenheit, oder vielleicht sogar gegenwärtig stattfindet, ist dabei egal.

Eine korrekte Verwendung des Futur II wäre z.B. dieser Satz:

> Er wird mich noch vor Weihnachten allein gelassen haben.

Das Ereignis B, das in der Zukunft liegt, sind die nächsten Weihnachten. Das Ereignis A ist das Alleingelassenwerden, und der Zeitpunkt dieser Alleinlassung liegt zeitlich vor den nächsten Weihnachten. In diesem Beispiel kann man aus dem Kontext schließen, dass das Ereignis A ebenfalls in der Zukunft stattfinden wird, Futur II lässt aber auch zu, dass das in der Vergangenheit war. Das soll das nächste Beispiel zeigen (Futur II im letzen Satz):

> *Arbeiter:* Wann können wir wieder gefahrlos in die Mine um weiter Gold abzubauen?
>
> *Polizist:* Sie müssen noch eine Stunde warten, dann ist es sicher. Der Attentäter hat nämlich vor genau 23 Stunden irgendwo in der Mine eine Bombe mit Zeitzünder versteckt. Wir haben in seiner Wohnung mehrere baugleiche Bomben gefunden, und alle haben einen einstellbaren Zünder, den man auf maximal 24 Stunden einstellen kann. Im Verhör hat er zugegeben, dass auch die versteckte Bombe einen solchen einstellbaren Zeitzünder hat, aber er hat uns nicht verraten, auf welche Zeitspanne der Zünder eingestellt ist. Wir wissen nur, dass es maximal 24 Stunden sein können.
> Hier im Freien bekommt man von der Detonation nichts mit. Wenn sie aber zufällig in der Mine in der Nähe der Bombe sind wenn sie hochgeht, werden Sie getötet.
> Ich kann Ihnen nur folgendes mit Sicherheit sagen: **Die Bombe wird in spätestens einer Stunde explodiert sein.**

Das Ereignis B ist der letztmögliche Zeitpunkt für die Explosion, und dieser Zeitpunkt liegt in der Zukunft.

Das Ereignis A ist die tatsächliche Explosion, und die hat mit großer Wahrscheinlichkeit bereits unbemerkt in der Vergangenheit stattgefunden.

---

Der Satz

> Er wird mich allein gelassen haben.

handelt nur vom Ereignis A und erwähnt den in der Zukunft liegenden Bezugspunkt nicht.  Es ist natürlich erlaubt, sich auf ein Ereignis B zu beziehen, das im Kontext vorhanden ist weil es zuvor das Gesprächsthema war, aber ohne diese Zusatzinformation ergibt der Satz alleine nicht viel Sinn.

Wenn aber klar ist, dass die nächsten Weihnachten dieses Ereignis B sind, dann sagt dieser Satz aus, dass der Kollege mich davor allein gelassen haben wird. Und ob er an Weihnachten wieder bei mir zurück ist, wird völlig offen gelassen.

---

Um auszudrücken, dass der Kollege mich an den Weihnachtsfeiertagen allein lässt, genügt Futur I:

> Er wird mich alleine lassen.

Das kann man natürlich um eine genaue Zeitangabe erweitern, die aber an der Zeitform des Prädikats nichts ändert:

> Er wird mich zu Weihnachten alleine lassen.